# Solutions of the Falkner Skan Equation for Negative Beta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications, boundary-value-problem

I was wondering what the solution to the Falkner Skan equation, $$f^{\prime\prime\prime}+ff^{\prime\prime}+\beta(1-f^{\prime 2})=0$$ looks like for negative values of $\beta$ and whether solutions for a particular values of $\beta$ are unique or if you could get multiple solutions for a given value of $\beta$?

The conditions for this equation are $f(0)=f^\prime(0)=0$ and $f^\prime(x)\rightarrow1$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Do you know the solutions for positive beta?

Comment: In general, such equation allows us to lower the order through the substitution $$f'=u(f)$$

Comment: "whether you solutions for a particular values of β are unique or if you could get multiple solutions for a given value of β" - you know that uniqueness of the solution depends on the initial/boundary conditions as well?

Comment: Yes, youre right, but I specified the Falkner Skan equation, for which the conditions are f(0)=f'(0)=0 and f'(x) ->1 as x->infinity.

Comment: Also the substiturion f'=u(f) wont work here to reduce the order, as there is an f term in the equation.

Comment: Alright, maybe you could add them to your post? I don't think this equation is widely known outside of hydrodynamics

Comment: @ JG221, that's exactly why this substitution would work

Comment: and yes I have found the soloution for positive beta with  a shooting algorithm using a 4th order Runge-Kutta method,  combined with newtons iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a remark due to the discussion in the comments.

Our equation is autonomous, because it doesn't contain the independent variable $x$.

$$f^{\prime\prime\prime}+ff^{\prime\prime}+\beta(1-f^{\prime 2})=0$$

So we can consider another function:

$$f'=u(f)$$

$$f''=\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{df}\frac{df}{dx}=u \cdot u'$$

$$f'''=\frac{d}{dx}(u \cdot u')=u \cdot \frac{d}{df}(u \cdot u')=u (u'^2+uu'')$$

So we obtain a second order equation:

$$u (u'^2+uu'')+f uu'+\beta(1-u^2)=0$$

> $$u^2 u''+u ~u'(u'+f)+\beta(1-u^2)=0$$

The boundary conditions are another story. From the first two conditions we know that $u(0)=0$, as for another condition, we'll need to work on that.

Note that for $u \to 1$ we can consider the approximate equation:

$$u u''+u'(u'+f)=0 \\ (u u')'+f u'=0 $$

And for $u \to 0$ another approximate equation:

$$u^2 u''+u ~u'(u'+f)+\beta=0$$